# MB Data affect on texting

Tags: sms

I have a Samsung model SM-S120VL phone that I bought through Tracfone. This may be specific to Tracfone, I'm not sure. The problem is at times I can not view text mesages sent to groups and I can not view images sent to me. If I try and send an image in a text the text will time-out and not send. I have correlated these problems with my Tracfone account showing zero in the MB DATA usage available. My son-in-law who is an Android user tells me that MB Data should not have anything to do with text images or my group text problems, so I'm confused. I am thinking about trading in Tracfone as a provider and going with Mobil, though I don't know if I would have the same problems.

Can someone tell me if this is a Tracfone only problem or specific to Android phones?

Answer (score 2):

## MMS uses data

The Multimedia Messaging Service uses data. Without data you can't receive or send MMS's. MMS's include photos, videos, audio, or sometimes group texting.

I am also a Trac phone user.